# How can you specify tab order in python flet?

Tags: python, user-interface, tabs, flet

I have a working flet input page, but the tab order seems to have no logic to it. I would like to specify exactly what I want, but don't know how. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused - the Tabs control changed the ordering? I've written 3 apps with Tabs and it never changed the order. Can you shouw me some code.

Here's mine and the order is as I create the control:

```
# Create the "tabbed" wlogin window for the app. 
tabs = ft.Tabs(selected_index = LOGINTAB, animation_duration = 300, 
           tabs = [
               ft.Tab(
                   text="Login",
                   content= logintab(page),),
        ft.Tab(
            text="Map",
            content=maptab(page),),
        ft.Tab(
            text="SQL",
            content=sqltab(page),),
        ft.Tab(
            text="Data",
            content=datatab(page),),
        ft.Tab(
            text="Export",
            content=exporttab(page),),
           ],
           expand = 1)
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion."Tab order" refers to the order in which controls are visited. Expected is of course left to right, top to bottom, but with more complex controls containing other controls that doesn't happen. I would like to be able to specify that ordering, as you can do in other Guis